# Filter table by multiple conditions: married women whose husbands are not already on the list

Tags: sql, join

I have a master table with data for men and women.
There are various fields: name, surname, date of birth, address, surname of the husband. The latter field is valued only for women (but not for all women, of course).

I need to create in MS Access or MySQL a second table with:

- all men (this is not a problem);
- all women without a spouse (this is also not a problem);
- married women whose husbands are not already on the list (comparing a woman's surname with that of their husband and address).

Input:

| name | surname | gender | husband's surname | city | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | s1 | m |  | c1 | a1 |
| n2 | s2 | f |  | c2 | a2 |
| n3 | s3 | f | s1 | c1 | a1 |
| n4 | s4 | f | s4 | c4 | a4 |

Result:

| name | surname | gender | husband's surname | city | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | s1 | m |  | c1 | a1 |
| n2 | s2 | f |  | c2 | a2 |
| n4 | s4 | f | s4 | c4 | a4 |

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: 1)  mysql and ms access are two different rdbms products with different implementations of sql. Which one do you use? 2) provide what you have done so far

Comment: What is your dbms product? Oracle? MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Not Exists` correlated query as the following:

```
Select * From tblname T
Where Not Exists (Select * From tblname D Where D.surname = T.husband_surname 
                  And D.address = T.address And D.gender = 'm')
/*And T.gender = 'f' un-comment this to get women only*/
```

Works on most DBMS. See a demo on MySql 8.0 from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6e7d227dd061083d4f38e5630fc6260).

Comment: Thanks for you help. It seems not work on my machine. I have about 400k records and it spend a lot time processing but never ending.

Comment: Does your table have indexes?

Answer (score 0):

For your given sample data, You can check the below query having left join -

```
SELECT D1.*
  FROM DATA D1
  LEFT JOIN DATA D2 ON D1.surname = D2.husband_surname
                   AND D1.address = D2.address
 WHERE D1.husband_surname IS NULL
    OR D1.name = D2.name;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07ae64625f02a1e69fab2315396af380)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help!
The query omits the records referring to women with the "husband's surname" field filled in but for which the husband is not in the list. Can you help me again?

Comment: Can you please update the example.